# Can this be done with Ultisnips?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I use UltiSnips for many of my TeX snippets, and I'm trying to create one to automatically insert a new `\item` inside `itemize` or `enumerate` environments.

The way it should work is the following: every time I'm done writing an `\item`, if I press the trigger key (`<tab>` for me) a function should be called that does the following:

1. If the tabstop corrisponding to that `\item` is empty, delete that line and jump out of the environment;
2. If it's not, create a new line with a new `\item` and a new tabstop after it.

I'm new to UltiSnips, but I think I can do this with a `post-jump` snippet action.

A skeleton of the possible code is the following

```
global !p
def new_tabstop_or_exit(item):
    # returns True if item has some non-whitespace chars
    if not item.isspace:
        # insert '\item' on the next line followed by a new tabstop
    else:
        # delete the current line and go to $0
endglobal

post_jump "if snip.tabstop == 0: new_tabstop_or_exit(snip.tabstops[snip.tabstop].current_text)"
snippet item "Itemize environment" b
\begin{itemize}
  \item $1
\end{itemize}
$0
endsnippet
```

`snip.tabstops` is the list with all tabstop objects, `snip.tabstop` is the number of the tabstop we jumped onto (see the [docs](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt), section 4.10.3).

So it should work something like this (`_`indicates the cursor position):

a. expand the snippet and place the cursor on the first tabstop

```
item<tab>
-->
\begin{itemize}
  \item _
\end{itemize}
```

b. tabstop `$1` is not empty, so create a new line with `\item` and a new tabstop following it (this can go on indefinitely)

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item this is a test<tab>
\end{itemize}
--> 
\begin{itemize}
  \item this is a test
  \item _
\end{itemize}
```

c. tabstop is left empty, delete the line and jump out of  `itemize` environment

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item this is a test
  \item _<tab>
\end{itemize}
--> 
\begin{itemize}
  \item this is a test
\end{itemize}
_
```

I hope I've been sufficiently clear. Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: if someone knows a way to do this via some other method/plugin please let me know, `UltiSnips` is just what came to my mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Main Ideas

There are 3 cases to consider (reworded slightly from the original question):
a) If not in an itemize environment, create one, and place the cursor after the first \item.
b) If in an itemize environment and if the list item is *not* empty, create a new \item.
c) If in an itemize environment and if the list item is empty, delete the line and jump out of itemize environment.

Instead of a single snippet, we define three snippets that address each of the cases separately:

```
# case a
context "not in_itemize(snip)"
snippet \item "start list of items" b
\begin{itemize}
    \item $1
\end{itemize}
endsnippet

# case b
context "in_itemize(snip)"
snippet "(^\s*)\\item\s*\S+.*$" "create next item" r
`!p snip.rv=match.group(0)`
`!p snip.rv=match.group(1)`\item $0
endsnippet

# case c
context "in_itemize(snip)"
post_jump "delline_exititemize(snip)"
snippet "^\s*\\item\s*" "exit itemize" r
endsnippet
```

- We use a **context** `in_itemize()` to check if we are in an itemize environment.
- For case c, we have used the **post_jump** action `delline_exititemize()` to manipulate the text buffer and cursor.
- We use different **regex snippets** to distinguish cases b and c.

---

### Snippet Details

Case a is the 'standard' snippet. It creates the itemize environment and places the cursor after \item.

Now we would like to distinguish between cases b and c. Instead of checking the tabstop's value, another way is to check if there are non-whitespace characters after \item (case b) or not (case c). This is done by a regular expression trigger, as seen by the 'r' at the end of the snippet header line. The regex `\S+` in case b checks if there are non-whitespace characters.

For case b, the line

```
`!p snip.rv=match.group(0)`
```

repeats the original text, and

```
`!p snip.rv=match.group(1)`\item $0
```

adds a new \item to the list.

`match.group(1)` captures the indentation of the previous line. This ensures that indentation is preserved.

For case c, the snippet doesn't produce any actual text. Rather, the post_jump action `delline_exititemize` manipulates the buffer and cursor positions, by removing the current line, and moving the cursor outside the itemize environment.

---

### Helpers for 'context' and 'post_jump'

We will have to write the two helper functions `in_itemize()` and `delline_exititemize()` in python (more precisely, using vim's python interface).

The code for the helper function `in_itemize()` is as follows:

```
def in_itemize(snip):
    # find using searchpairpos('\begin{itemize}','','\end{itemize}','bnWz')
    beginpos = vim.eval("searchpairpos('\\\\begin{itemize}','','\\\\end{itemize}','bnWz')")
    endpos   = vim.eval("searchpairpos('\\\\begin{itemize}','','\\\\end{itemize}', 'nWz')")
    curpos   = snip.cursor.to_vim_cursor()
    if beginpos == ['0','0'] or endpos == ['0','0']: return False
    if posCompare(beginpos, curpos) < 0 and posCompare(curpos, endpos) < 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This uses vim's `searchpairpos()` function to find the locations of \begin{itemize} and \end{itemize}. It is wrapped with `vim.eval()` since we are calling the vim function in python. These start and end positions are then compared with the cursor's position.
In short, this function checks if the cursor is encompassed by \begin{itemize} and \end{itemize}.

(The function `posCompare` is rather straightforward to implement. It is included in the full code below)

---

The code for deleting the current line and exiting the itemize environment is as follows:

```
def delline_exititemize(snip):
    cursorline = snip.cursor[0] 
    del snip.buffer[cursorline]

    # add blank line after \end{itemize}
    snip.buffer.append("\n", cursorline + 1 + 1)
    # cursorline+1 is the linenr (1-based)

    # place cursor on blank line after \end{itemize}
    snip.cursor.set(cursorline+1, 0)
```

This deletes the current line, adds a new line after \end{itemize}, and moves the cursor to the desired location. We have used the properties of `snip` to achieve this. See `:h UltiSnips-custom-context-snippets` paragraph 6, for details. Note that we have to convert between 0-based and 1-based indexing.

---

### Putting all pieces together

We have now filled in all parts. The last step is to place all python code in a `global !p ... endglobal` block, or in a separate file in .vim/pythonx. For the former approach, here is the full code:

```
# helpers

global !p
def delline_exititemize(snip):
    cursorline = snip.cursor[0] 
    del snip.buffer[cursorline]

    # add blank line after \end{itemize}
    snip.buffer.append("\n", cursorline + 1 + 1)
    # cursorline+1 is the linenr (1-based)

    # place cursor on blank line after \end{itemize}
    snip.cursor.set(cursorline+1, 0)


def in_itemize(snip):
    # find using searchpairpos('\begin{itemize}','','\end{itemize}','bnWz')
    beginpos = vim.eval("searchpairpos('\\\\begin{itemize}','','\\\\end{itemize}','bnWz')")
    endpos   = vim.eval("searchpairpos('\\\\begin{itemize}','','\\\\end{itemize}', 'nWz')")
    curpos   = snip.cursor.to_vim_cursor()
    if beginpos == ['0','0'] or endpos == ['0','0']: return False
    if posCompare(beginpos, curpos) < 0 and posCompare(curpos, endpos) < 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def posCompare(cur1, cur2):
    """ returns -1 if cur1 is before cur2, +1 if after, and 0 if cur1==cur2
        cur1, cur2 are required to be lists of the form [row,col]
    """
    cur1r = int(cur1[0])
    cur1c = int(cur1[1])
    cur2r = int(cur2[0])
    cur2c = int(cur2[1])
    if   cur1r < cur2r: return -1
    elif cur1r > cur2r: return  1
    else:
        if   cur1c < cur2c: return -1
        elif cur1c > cur2c: return  1
        else: return 0
endglobal


# snippets

context "not in_itemize(snip)"
snippet \item "start list of items" b
\begin{itemize}
    \item $1
\end{itemize}
endsnippet

context "in_itemize(snip)"
snippet "(^\s*)\\item\s*\S+.*$" "create next item" r
`!p snip.rv=match.group(0)`
`!p snip.rv=match.group(1)`\item $0
endsnippet

context "in_itemize(snip)"
post_jump "delline_exititemize(snip)"
snippet "^\s*\\item\s*" "exit itemize" r
endsnippet
```

Answer (score 1):

What about writing your own mapping for TAB that analyses its context?

- if it detect `^\s*\\item\s*$` on the current line, it clears the line then jumps over the end of the current itemize/enumerate/... environment
- otherwise it runs the default mapping.

In [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets), I have a function that may help to override existing mappings: `lh#bracket#enrich_imap()`

```
" ~/.vim/ftplugin/tex/youritem.vim
call lh#brackets#enrich_imap('<tab>',
    \ { 'condition': 'getline(".") =~ "^\\s*\\\\item\\s*$"',
    \   'action': 'YourFunctionThatDeleteAndJumpAndYouLlHaveToWrite()' },
    \ 1} " -> buffer local => restricted to (La)TeX
```

Sorry I won't break down my function here as it's not trivial and made of several other functions. For information, the starting point is `maparg()` to extract the existing mapping. Then, it's about testing conditions to return the associated action, evaluated. If no condition match, the default mapping is evaluated.

PS: if you wish to re-implement my function, it's possible you may not have it define a `:map-<expr>` depending on how you proceed. Indeed you want to jump, and `map-<expr>` is quite limited in this area.